# Unable to open online streaming PDF in browser

Tags: android, xamarin

How to open a online stream assets in android.

I had used Intent, but the file gets downloaded and not getting opened in browser.

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Don't want to use Web view. Any help ?

Comment: Am getting only the PDF URL though APi and dont have it stored in the device. It  gets loaded in iOS without any issues, but  not the case in android.

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How to open a online stream assets in android.

You could using google doc service to achieve this function, it just need you 
 to modify your `Url` like this :

```
string Url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + strPdf;
//Eg :string Url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + "https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Url);
```

Comment: No this is not solved. It gives an security violation error.